# Port the hbase on .net

Tags: java, .net, hbase

I want to access my `hbase` cluster from `.net`. Although, I am able to connect through `java` `hbase` client. So, anyone has ported the hbase for the `.net` or tell me how should i use my java client from .net?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HBase from .NET via the [Thrift](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/ThriftApi) & [REST](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate) APIs
[Someone already did](http://www.nuget.org/packages/hbase-sharp/) a crude C# binding around the thrift ones